# Does Azcopy support moving and removing files

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

My question is: Does AZCOPY support moving and removing files from disk after copy to Azure storage?

Answer (score 1):

From the local disk, no, it only copies to the cloud and does not take responsibility for any deletion or move. Best practice is to wrap your AzCopy in a script that takes care of the local file handling based on a successful response from AzCopy.

You could roll your own version using the [Storage Data Movement Library](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/).

Comment: Ok so great. Nice